# Lumen not support email address in route?

Tags: api, lumen

I will developing RestFul API with Lumen, but I got some problem.
When I try to get user with email. I got message

"The requested resource /user/test@example.com was not found on this server."

Here my route

```
 $router->get('/{email}', ['as' => 'get', 'uses' => 'UserController@show']);
```

I try same url in laravel, but It works. I don't know why?
Anyone can suggest or help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

In lumen Routes are like below

```
$app->get('/user/{email}', 'ThorController@show');
```

For more information : https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters

Also check your database credentials whether you are using different database for api then laravel application

Comment: I am using it in my lumen api routes. it works in my api's

Comment: which version of lumen you are using?

Comment: I using latest version

Comment: check your database credentials whether you are using different database for api

Comment: check my edited answer may be you are using wrong path in route `/user/{email}` will help

Comment: FYI : I run app through serve command. It should be root cause?